# memory leak (?) after sqlite+fmdb vacuum command

Tags: ios, sqlite, fmdb

I'm using sqlite in my app via the FMDB wrapper.

Memory usage in my app sits at 2.25 MB before a call to VACUUM:

```
[myFmdb executeUpdate: @"VACUUM;" ];
```

Afterwords its at 5.8 MB, and I can't seem to reclaim the memory.  Post-vacuum, the Instruments/Allocations tool shows tons of sqlite3MemMalloc calls with live bytes, each allocating 1.5 K.

Short of closing the database and reopening it (an option), how can I clean this up?

**Edit**:  closing and reopening the database connection does clear up the memory.  This is my solution unless someone can shed some further insight to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted this question on the sqlite-users list and got a response that suggested reducing the cache size for sqlite.  This is done by executing the following statement (adjusting the size value as desired):

```
pragma cache_size = 100
```

EDIT:  here's another nifty trick for releasing SQLite memory.  Be sure to #define SQLITE_ENABLE_MEMORY_MANAGEMENT.

Documented here:  http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/release_memory.html

```
int bytesReleased = sqlite3_release_memory( 0x7fffffff );
NSLog( @"sqlite freed %d bytes", bytesReleased );
```