# iOS - FMDB usage and memory

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite, fmdb

I have been tracking down memory leaks in my iOS app and I keep coming back to the following code using the leaks instrument:

```
NSMutableArray *resultSet = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];

NSAutoreleasePool *innerPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:query,equipmentID];
while ([rs next])
{
    [resultSet addObject: [rs resultDict]];
}
[rs close];
[innerPool release];

return [resultSet autorelease];
```

Is this the correct (in terms of memory management) usage of FMDB?  Here is a screenshot of the leaks instrument:

[leaks](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-bX_WthVhsUU/TjgKhe_LA8I/AAAAAAAAMs8/C8KCgxtLPaQ/s800/memoryLeaks.jpg)

Detailed Screenshot of the leak:

[detail](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-ZbnV40_WTrg/TjhOQKjBB4I/AAAAAAAAMtU/1tIUgWIT_MM/s800/leak2.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct memory management.  The `[rs close];` line is technically unnecessary, because it will happen (if it hasn't already) when the `FMResultSet` is deallocated (as part of the pool draining).  But putting it in there explicitly is fine.

Is it possible you're over-retaining the return array?

Comment: Thanks Dave, yes I am over-retaining the return array. Each item gets retained (via a synthesized setter) by a UITableView cell subclass.  These are in a reusable queue, may be something I don't understand about how the queue works.  [detail](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-ZbnV40_WTrg/TjhOQKjBB4I/AAAAAAAAMtU/1tIUgWIT_MM/s800/leak2.jpg) See screenshot of the leak, the BaseCell setData method is the only one without a release.  If I add [data release] to the dealloc on the basecell, I get a crash.  Any ideas on why this would be crashing when it looks to be clearly retained via the setter?

Comment: The smoking gun turned out to be the following line: 'while ([rs next])
    {
        result = [rs resultDict];
    }' .... This was being called after the cell saved its data, and I believe that a direct assignment like this is a bad idea, I changed it to 'while ([rs next])
    {
        result = [[rs resultDict] copy];
    }'

Comment: At first I agreed with Crake about copying the dictionary, but it is not necessary since fmdb is already calling `copy`.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite allocates and keeps a bunch of memory, which is only freed when the database is closed.  You can also adjust how much memory it will allocate by issuing a 'pragma cache_size = nnn' command.

See this related question and answer:

[memory leak (?) after sqlite+fmdb vacuum command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239040/memory-leak-after-sqlitefmdb-vacuum-command)